# Can I convert model with one of its associations to YAML format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to print ActiveRecord model in YAML format for debugging purposes.

Currently I invoke `model.to_yaml`. But it doesn't return model's associations

How can I convert model with one of its associations to YAML format?

Answer (score 11):

You can convert to json first. The default ActiveRecord `as_json` method allows you to include assocations. From there, it's straightforward to convert to yaml. Example:

```
menu.as_json(include: :dishes).to_yaml
```

Comment: Thanks, @JellicleCat. I just tested my original answer on rails 3.2.13, and found that the `include` option did nothing when passed to the `to_yaml` method. I updated my answer to suggest converting to json first (which respects the `include` option), then converting to yaml.

Comment: Thanks, @Sixty4Bit. I had a bug in my answer – needed to change `to_json` to `as_json`. The updated answer works as tested in rails 3 and 4.

Comment: Excellent! I love it when I get to reverse a down vote!

Answer (score 4):

to_yaml ignores the include-parameter ... but you could do the following:

```
Hash.from_xml(menu.to_xml include: :dishes).to_yaml
```