# rails find with related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm starting on rails 4.xx

What is the best way on rails to find relationships belongs_to or has_many
I try to have something similar to the containable behavior of cakephp

I try SEVERAL thing but I do not really find a solution, with all the different version of rails.

we can do it with ruby? imbri object ? if not..... How you done something similar?

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end
```

**@example.** = Article.all

```
- !ruby/object:Article
  attributes:
    id: 1
    nb_acces: 1
    user_id: 1
              id: 1
              title: admin

    title: dsadasd
    slug: sadsa
    category_id: 3
                id: 3
                title: dsadasd

    summary: asdas
    content: dsadsa
    online: 1
    top: 1
    photo: fsdfsd
    photo_dir: dfsdf
    comment_count: 1
    created_at: 2014-07-09 10:28:50.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-07-09 10:48:16.000000000 Z

- !ruby/object:Article
  attributes:
    id: 2
    nb_acces: 1
    user_id: 1
              id: 1
              title: admin

    title: dsadasd
    slug: sadsa
    category_id: 3
                id: 3
                title: dsadasd

    summary: asdas
    content: dsadsa
    online: 1
    top: 1
    photo: fsdfsd
    photo_dir: dfsdf
    comment_count: 1
    created_at: 2014-07-09 10:28:50.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-07-09 10:48:16.000000000 Z

instead of

- !ruby/object:Article
  attributes:
    id: 1
    nb_acces: 1
    user_id: 1
    title: dsadasd
    slug: sadsa
    category_id: 3
    summary: asdas
    content: dsadsa
    online: 1
    top: 1
    photo: fsdfsd
    photo_dir: dfsdf
    comment_count: 1
    created_at: 2014-07-09 10:28:50.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-07-09 10:48:16.000000000 Z
```

Comment: Can you rephrase? I have no clue what you're trying to say.

Comment: sorry my english is bad.

Comment: There is something on rails, like cakephp to find the relationship?
Like the containable behavior => http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: You can just do `Article.find(article_id).user` if you have your relationships setup if that is what you mean. I am also having trouble understanding what you mean.

Comment: If I've not mistaken, then you're asking how do you eager load associations so that you don't run n+1 queries? for that you can do: `Article.includes(:user, :category).find(1)` it'll load article with id 1 and it's related associations: `user` and `category` and if you do: `Article.includes(:user, :category).find(1).to_json(include: {user: [:id, :title], category: [:id, :title]} )` then you'll get something similar to the link you've posted. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Also, I won't suggest for this(as it will slow down your application) but, anyways if you need to find all articles you can do: `Article.includes(:user, :category).all` to load related category and user for the related Articles.

Comment: For general info on on this kind of thing: if you'd like to learn more about the queries you can do, this is the guide to read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html 
All the things that you can do on a general collection (eg Article.where().includes().all) can also be done on an associated collection (eg user.articles.where().includes().all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the relationships are lazy loaded unless you specify otherwise. While the data may not show up in your YAML export the data is available.

```
article = Article.first
author_name = article.user.name
```

The above will execute two SQL queries to retrieve the data, one for article and one for the user. It will retrieve the user record and populate the author_name with the user's name value. The same goes for category, it will be available as well and will execute another SQL query to retrieve the data.

```
articles = Article.all
author_names = articles.collect {|a| a.user.name}
```

The above is an n+1 query, it will execute 1 query for the articles and then 1 query for each article to get the user. If you have 20 articles you will execute 20 author queries plus the one article query. This is inefficient so you should include the user.

```
articles = Article.includes(:user).all
author_names = articles.collect {|a| a.user.name}
```

The above will only execute 2 queries no matter how many articles there are. If you want to get the users and categories just include both of them:

```
articles = Article.includes(:user, :category).all
author_names = articles.collect {|a| a.user.name}
category_names = articles.collect {|a| a.category.name}
```

This will execute a total of 3 queries.

Also, if you are trying to [get the YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409772/can-i-convert-model-with-one-of-its-associations-to-yaml-format) you will have to convert to xml and do an include:

```
puts Hash.from_xml(articles.to_xml(include: [:user, :category])).to_yaml
```

Comment: ok thank you...
Queries works well.
So there is no containable in rails.
I have now 3 variables.(articles, authors, categorie)

I'll work this!
Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: No, there isn't a containable. Rails by default gives you only the records from the model requested and the lazy loads when you request data from associations. Or... You can include an association to get the associated records eagerly.